# Why I'm getting different language in terminal while using Flutter commands?

Tags: windows, flutter, command-line, flutter-doctor

I've installed Flutter SDK from https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows then I've extracted the file to folder C:\Users\ACER\Documents then I've copied the path of the bin folder of flutter from the extracted location then set it to the environment variables to my PC. Then when I'm checking the commands of flutter in command prompt I'm getting some words which are not English like [re'V^], screenshot attached below. The default language in my pc is english and I want flutter to be in English too. How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: https://www.betterhostreview.com/change-language-in-command-prompt.html

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1309399/change-display-language-in-windows-10-with-cmd-or-powershell-commands